# Googlesheet PHP API inserting duplicate rows in spreadsheet

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

After spending a few hours, I developed a script to insert records in Google spreadsheet but every time I'm running the script from browser, it is inserting **two rows** in the Spreadsheet.
The second row is a duplicate row which I don't want to insert.

Below is my code

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Booking App");
$client->setScopes([Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS]);
$client->setAuthConfig("sheets_api_secret.json");
$client->setAccessToken("xxxxxxx");

$service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);

$options = array('valueInputOption' => 'RAW');
$range = "Sheet1!A1:G";
$values = [
    ["NV1506127", "15-06-2020", "John", "Doe", "959xxxxxx", "example@gmail.com", "12345"]
];
$body   = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange(['range' => $range, 'majorDimension' => 'ROWS', 'values' => $values]);

$result = $service->spreadsheets_values->append("xxxxxxxxxxxx", $range, $body, $options);
print($result->updates->updatedRange. PHP_EOL);

?>
```

Please help me with this issue.

Response which I'm getting after running the script from browser -

```
    [updates] => Google_Service_Sheets_UpdateValuesResponse Object
    (
        [spreadsheetId] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        [updatedCells] => 7
        [updatedColumns] => 7
        [updatedDataType:protected] => Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange
        [updatedDataDataType:protected] => 
        [updatedRange] => Sheet1!A43:G43
        [updatedRows] => 1
        [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [modelData:protected] => Array
            (
            )

        [processed:protected] => Array
            (
            )

    )
```

Comment: The logical answer is your code is being fired 2x.  How do you call/fire it?

Comment: What does your `print()` output show?  What does `$result->getUpdates()->getUpdatedCells()` show?

Comment: @Don't Panic: My script is getting fired from browser.

Comment: print() function is showing that only 1 row is inserted. The output of print($result->updates->updatedRange. PHP_EOL); is - Sheet1!A35:G35

Comment: @Don'tPanic: The output of print_r($result->updates) is - Google_Service_Sheets_UpdateValuesResponse Object ( [spreadsheetId] => 1Z6zTEsYA9xlw9QJce4DKyDUPnEthEeJxkceUiNil1KI [updatedCells] => 7 [updatedColumns] => 7 [updatedDataType:protected] => Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange [updatedDataDataType:protected] => [updatedRange] => Sheet1!A45:G45 [updatedRows] => 1 [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array ( ) [modelData:protected] => Array ( ) [processed:protected] => Array ( ) )

Comment: That is hard to read (edit your question, add it there, with formatting), but AFAICT it says updated rows was 1, right?  So it seems like your code is being called 2x, each time updating 1 row?

Comment: Thanks @Don'tPanic, I've updated the question and placed my response which I'm getting from the browser but when I run the same script from CLI, it enters only one record in the Google sheet.

Comment: So - `[updatedRows] => 1` looks correct, right?  If it runs once in the browser, 1 row is updated.  If it runs 2x, you would still see the same response (bcs you are only looking at the last time it ran).  And running from CLI is also correct.  So far, there is nothing to disprove the logical explanation I first proposed - your code is being fired 2x in the browser.  How are you calling it in the browser?  Have you checked browser devtools and looked at network requests?  Are you calling it via AJAX, and forgetting to do `e.preventDefault()`, or something like that?

Comment: Thanks @Don'tPanic, it's plain PHP script without any other logic as I wanted to create a working script first with hardcoded array values as given in my question and wanted to put the actual logic later on. I've not used any AJAX in it, I'm hitting a URL in the browser and response shows 1 row updated but actually there are two rows getting inserted in the Google sheet. To finish my work I actually added that file in CRON with actual logic as it was working properly there but for browser I couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who is looking for an API that can write data in Google Spreadsheet can use the above script by replacing the 'accessToken' and 'Spreadsheet' ID. It is a working script. Make sure you are running your script from the browser. Just check if your script is entring one record in the spreadsheet or two.
I'm running this script from command line which fixed my issue.